# How to show/hide content using jquery 'show()' or 'hide()'

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to Make sure the sidebar is opened (using show(), when the button with id `#open-sidebar` is clicked. And, closes/hide() if clicked on button with id `#close-sidebar` I have created the following functions to achieve it. The functions are not working??

```js
function showSidebar() {
  $('#open-sidebar').show();
}

function hideSidebar() {
  $('#close-sidebar').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu">
  <!-- Close button for sidebar -->
  <button id="close-sidebar" class="btn-square pull-right sidebar-control" onclick="hideSidebar()">
          <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
       </button>
  <h2><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> Cities</h2>
  <ul id="citylist" class="list-group">
    <li>India</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<header id="mainview-header" class="header topbar text-white">
  <!-- Menu button for opening the sidebar -->
  <button id="open-sidebar" class="btn-square pull-left sidebar-control" onclick="showSidebar()">
         <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
  <h1 id="city" class="pull-left text-center city">Berlin</h1>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</header>
<div id="icon">
  <img id="iconimage" src="img/rain.png" alt="weather">
</div>
<div id="summary" class="text-center">Rain in the afternoon</div>
<div id="temperature" class="text-center">11° C</div>
```

Comment: #open-sidebar is the id of the button. You have to use the id or class of the sidebar. for example $('#idOfSidebar').show();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong selectors. You want to hide and show the ***navbar*** not the buttons:

```
function showSidebar() {
    $('#menu').show();
}
function hideSidebar() {
    $('#menu').hide();
}
```

Comment: No problem whatsoever, my friend!

Answer (score 3):

You need to capture the click event on the open and close buttons, and apply the show and hide functions to the sidebar itself:

```
// showSidebar
$('#open-sidebar').click(function() {
  $('#sidebar').show();
});
$('#close-sidebar').click(function() {
  $('#sidebar').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont mix inline with event handlers. You almost had it.

For adding event handler use as above

```js
$('#open-sidebar').click(showSidebar);
$('#close-sidebar').click(hideSidebar);

function showSidebar() {
  alert('show')
}

function hideSidebar() {
  alert('hide')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
html code for reference.

<nav id="menu">
  <!-- Close button for sidebar -->
  <button id="close-sidebar" class="btn-square pull-right sidebar-control">
      <i class="fa fa-close">close</i>
   </button>
  <h2><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> Cities</h2>
  <ul id="citylist" class="list-group">
    <li>India</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<header id="mainview-header" class="header topbar text-white">
  <!-- Menu button for opening the sidebar -->
  <button id="open-sidebar" class="btn-square pull-left sidebar-control">
     <i class="fa fa-bars">open</i>
  </button>
  <h1 id="city" class="pull-left text-center city">Berlin</h1>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</header>
<div id="icon">
  <img id="iconimage" src="img/rain.png" alt="weather">
</div>
<div id="summary" class="text-center">Rain in the afternoon</div>
<div id="temperature" class="text-center">11° C</div>
```

For inline use below

```js
function showSidebar() {
  alert('show')
}

function hideSidebar() {
  alert('hide')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
html code for reference.

<nav id="menu">
  <!-- Close button for sidebar -->
  <button id="close-sidebar" class="btn-square pull-right sidebar-control" onclick='hideSidebar()'>
      <i class="fa fa-close">close</i>
   </button>
  <h2><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> Cities</h2>
  <ul id="citylist" class="list-group">
    <li>India</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<header id="mainview-header" class="header topbar text-white">
  <!-- Menu button for opening the sidebar -->
  <button id="open-sidebar" class="btn-square pull-left sidebar-control" onclick='showSidebar()'>
     <i class="fa fa-bars">open</i>
  </button>
  <h1 id="city" class="pull-left text-center city">Berlin</h1>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</header>
<div id="icon">
  <img id="iconimage" src="img/rain.png" alt="weather">
</div>
<div id="summary" class="text-center">Rain in the afternoon</div>
<div id="temperature" class="text-center">11° C</div>
```